# Is it necessary to run 10 replications of boosted regression model if using dismo in R?

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation

I am trying to use the dismo package to build up a BRT model with presence-only data. I have randomly sampled 10 000 background data. My questions is:
do I need to run 10 (or 5) replications of the brt model on the dataset like a conventional cv procedure? For example, for each replication, 60% of the presence data and 60% of the background data will be used for training the model, and the rest presence data for test. The average of the prediction maps will be the result.  However, in the dismo package, the gbm.step method already uses cv to derive the optimal number of trees, so I am wondering if I can just put all the presence data and the background data to generate the optimal model?

Thanks a lot!